# Can you obtain the parent theme's type programmatically on Android?

Tags: android

I would like to check **programatically** the parent of the theme I'm using, in order to differentiate between AppCompat.Light & AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

I know I can do the following, but it doesn't seem to give any obvious identifiers to suggest its parent:

`Theme myTheme = appContext.getTheme();`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just inherit from an intermediate theme where you've defined a theme attribute, e.g. add attribute `themeType` with enum values `dark` and `light`, then specify `app:themeType="light"` in your light parent theme?